# How to shuffle list except an element?

Tags: java, shuffle

I have a list integer with value elements : **0, 7, 2, 1, 6, 5.**

I know that I can use method

```
Collections.shuffle(list);
```

to shuffle my list. But I do not want change value of 2nd position. It should be always 7.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can shuffle the Collection and then restore the 7 to the 2nd position :

```
Collections.shuffle(list);
list.set(list.indexOf(7),list.get(2));
list.set(2,7);
```

Or shorter :

```
Collections.shuffle(list);
Collections.swap(list, 2, list.indexOf(7));
```

As others suggested, you can also remove the element whose location you wish to preserve prior to the shuffling, and add it later to the same location.

Both ways should take similar time for ArrayLists (linear at the worst case), since in my answer `indexOf` would take linear time, but removing and adding an element in the alternative solution (especially if the index is close to the start of the list) would take linear time for `ArrayList`, since all the elements following the removed/added index has to be pushed to a new index.

Comment: And if you are not aware of the element’s value and just want to preserve it at the second position, you could remove it before shuffling and afterwards add it to the second position.

Comment: @NuongReo The first snippet won't duplicate the value of 7. If 7 stayed in the 2 index after the shuffle, both set operations would be the same - `list.set(2,7)` and won't change anything, since `set` doesn't add a value to the List (it only changes an existing value).

Comment: For documentation: this preserves the distribution property of `Collections.shuffle(...)`.

Answer (score 6):

To easily prevent moving any number of elements simply

- Remove them from list,
- shuffle rest of elements,
- put them back at their original position (start from left to avoid problem with elements shifting to the right).

Answer (score 2):

There's an alternative solution which is longer, but probably faster for long lists:

```
public static <T> void shuffleExcept(final List<T> list, final int position) {
    List<T> view = new AbstractList<T>() {
        @Override
        public T get(int index) {
            return list.get(index >= position ? index+1 : index);
        }

        @Override
        public T set(int index, T element) {
            return list.set(index >= position ? index+1 : index, element);
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return list.size()-1;
        }
    };
    Collections.shuffle(view);
}
```

Here we create a "view" of original list which is the whole list except the element we want to preserve (we just shift the indices of subsequent elements). Next we shuffle this view. That's the beauty of interfaces: you can ask the existing method to do something different just passing the new interface implementation.

Usage example:

```
List<Integer> input = Arrays.asList(0, 7, 2, 1, 6, 5);
shuffleExcept(input, 1);
System.out.println(input);
shuffleExcept(input, 1);
System.out.println(input);
shuffleExcept(input, 1);
System.out.println(input);
shuffleExcept(input, 1);
System.out.println(input);
shuffleExcept(input, 1);
System.out.println(input);
shuffleExcept(input, 1);
System.out.println(input);
shuffleExcept(input, 1);
System.out.println(input);
```

Typical output:

```
[6, 7, 5, 2, 1, 0]
[5, 7, 6, 1, 2, 0]
[6, 7, 2, 0, 5, 1]
[6, 7, 2, 0, 5, 1]
[2, 7, 0, 5, 6, 1]
[6, 7, 0, 2, 5, 1]
[5, 7, 2, 0, 1, 6]
```